# How can i get IP address in worklight?

Tags: ip, ibm-mobilefirst

I am unable to get ip address of client using this following code. How can i modify this code? Please help me

**This is .js code**

```
function getIP(){
    //return WL.Server.configuration["local.IPAddress"];
    //alert(publicWorklightHostname);
    var request = WL.Server.getClientRequest();alert('IP');
    var ip = request.getHeader('x-client-ip');
    alert(ip);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
var request = WL.Server.getClientRequest();
var IPAddress = request.getHeader('x-forwarded-for');
```

Edit:

Also you can try this

```
WL.Device.getNetworkInfo(function (networkInfo) {
alert (networkInfo.ipAddress); 
});
```

Comment: i found also this:  https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/10123/how-do-you-get-the-original-ip-doing-the-request-to-your-bluemix-app.html

Comment: Above link also didn't helped for me. Please make sure that i am using Hybrid App in worklight

Comment: Look at my Edit. Maybe this can help you

Comment: Thank you Smudoo for paying patience on my question but it didn't worked

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll hope you find an answer